# Why do I get "reverse accessor for 'model.user' clashes with reverse accessor for 'model.account' even though I set AUTH_USER_MODEL?

Tags: django, django-models

I've seen the same question posted a few times, and the answer is always.. did you set `AUTH_USER_MODEL`?

Here is the snippet from my settings.py file.

```
## Accounts

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.Account'
```

Here is the error message I am getting when I try to generate migrations for my new model.

```
ERRORS:
admin.LogEntry.user: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'LogEntry.user' clashes with reverse accessor for 'LogEntry.account'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'LogEntry.user' or 'LogEntry.account'.
logs.LogEntry.account: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'LogEntry.account' clashes with reverse accessor for 'LogEntry.user'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'LogEntry.account' or 'LogEntry.user'.
```

Here is the model that is causing the problem.

```
class LogEntry(models.Model):
    log = models.ForeignKey(Log, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    account = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    entry = models.TextField()
```

I'm developing on sqlite3, so I have tried destroying the sqlite file and emptying my migrations folders.

I run the command again and get the same result.

I know that I could define a `related_name` on the field, but I would rather address the underlying problem. It shouldn't class with `LogEntry.user` because I am not creating any association between those models directly... or am I?

Comment: It looks like you also have a `user = models.ForeignKey(...)` model, but you did not share that part?

Comment: I don't. That is the entire model.

Comment: Then why does it speak about "**admin.LogEntry.user**: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'LogEntry.user' clashes with reverse accessor for 'LogEntry.account'"?

Comment: Hold on, you have **two** `LogEntry` models?

Comment: No, I have one `LogEntry` model. I do have another model named `Log` which may or may not be relevant here.

Comment: well the error mesaage speaks of a `LogEntry` model in the `admin` module. Perhaps that is not one you wrote yourself, but the point is that you have two models with the same name, hence the automatically derived `related_name=...` will of course "clash".

Comment: Ahh, I see... [LogEntry](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/) is a model in admin! Thank you a bunch.